# Azure VMs and load balancing

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

am new to windows azure. I recently set up a vm and host a website, according to the SLA i need to have 2 VMs in the availability set. Now i did set up the second VM.

My questions what do i need to use the second VM for?

if i setup load balancing does azure redirect user to the second VM? this second VM has nothing in it.

Please i will like to know this and is it possible to replicate the content of the first VM to the second one, so each time the first one is down the second VM can take over.

Thanks

Comment: I think first you need to understand the basics of cloud computing. Try Microsoft Azure Essentials: Fundamentals of Azure. It's free on this link http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/ebooks#top

Answer (score 0):

1. Both VMs need to be running the same application services
2. Both VMs need to be in the same Availability Set
3. You need to configure a public endpoint on each Azure VM that is part of a load-balanced set

There is no "automatic" high availability. There are only load balancing and OS-level availability guarantees. Aside from that, it is your responsibility to ensure that the application is installed and correctly functioning on each VM that is part of the Availability Set and Load-balanced Set.

Comment: i really appreciate this, now i understand.. so i need to replicate the data and service to the other VM. But any idea on how i could go about this.?